# apigee oauth2 generates new access token everytime

Tags: oauth-2.0, apigee

I am trying my hands on apigee. I have configured a proxy with oauth2.0 security.

Everything works fine. But I noticed that a new access token is generated everytime I hit the `oauth2/accesstoken` endpoint, eventhough the previous one has not expired.

So as a consequence my endpoint is accessible with more than one token at a time. I am not an oauth2 expert, but isn't this a security risk? If we have so many accesstokens floating around. Please clarify.
 Is this the usual implementation of every oauth2 server or is it specific to apigee and if so why?

My assumption is that for a particular client key/secret there would be only one valid access token at any given time and when this expires, the client should request for a new token using refresh token. Is this wrong?

Comment: No, this is the usual implementation of oauth2. There can be multiple access token floating around and thus the TTL for these tokens should be less (30-60 mins). But if you want to use the same token, you can use response cache policies to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ResponseCache policy for lookup/populate cache. It's a read through cache policy.

Answer (score 0):

Use **PopulateCache** and **LookupCache** Policy.